symbolic reference class is not accessible: class sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo, from interface spark.sql.catalyst.util.SparkDateTimeUtils
While trying to write Spark (v4.0-preview1) Dataframe to database table (SQL Server) with JDBC driver. Getting the following error.
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: symbolic reference class is not accessible: class sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo, from interface org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.SparkDateTimeUtils (unnamed module @7bbc8656)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:955) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.checkSymbolicClass(MethodHandles.java:3686) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:3646) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.findVirtual(MethodHandles.java:2680) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.SparkDateTimeUtils.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$util$SparkDateTimeUtils$$getOffsetsByWallHandle(SparkDateTimeUtils.scala:206) ~[spark-sql-api_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.SparkDateTimeUtils.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$util$SparkDateTimeUtils$$getOffsetsByWallHandle$(SparkDateTimeUtils.scala:201) ~[spark-sql-api_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$util$SparkDateTimeUtils$$getOffsetsByWallHandle$lzycompute(DateTimeUtils.scala:41) ~[spark-catalyst_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$util$SparkDateTimeUtils$$getOffsetsByWallHandle(DateTimeUtils.scala:41) ~[spark-catalyst_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.SparkDateTimeUtils.toJavaDate(SparkDateTimeUtils.scala:228) ~[spark-sql-api_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.SparkDateTimeUtils.toJavaDate$(SparkDateTimeUtils.scala:223) ~[spark-sql-api_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.toJavaDate(DateTimeUtils.scala:41) ~[spark-catalyst_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils.toJavaDate(DateTimeUtils.scala) ~[spark-catalyst_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificSafeProjection.createExternalRow_0_2$(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificSafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.next(Iterator.scala:584) ~[scala-library-2.13.14.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.next(Iterator.scala:584) ~[scala-library-2.13.14.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:806) ~[spark-sql_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$saveTable$1(JdbcUtils.scala:978) ~[spark-sql_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$saveTable$1$adapted(JdbcUtils.scala:977) ~[spark-sql_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:1042) ~[spark-core_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted(RDD.scala:1042) ~[spark-core_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2501) ~[spark-core_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93) ~[spark-core_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:171) ~[spark-core_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:146) ~[spark-core_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$5(Executor.scala:640) ~[spark-core_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64) ~[spark-common-utils_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61) ~[spark-common-utils_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:99) ~[spark-core_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:643) [spark-core_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) [?:?]

Below is an excerpt from my pom.xml as per Chris' suggestions. Hope this helps!

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-boot.repackage.skip>true</spring-boot.repackage.skip>
    
        <!-- SPARK-36796 for JDK-17 test-->
        <extraJavaTestArgs>
            -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
            --add-modules=jdk.incubator.vector
            --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED
            -Djdk.reflect.useDirectMethodHandle=false
            -Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true
        </extraJavaTestArgs>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
    <!--        all other dependencies-->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <jvmArguments>
                    --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED
                </jvmArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

Also, tried the above options with --add-exports. But couldn't resolve the issue!
This seems to be fixed as per this pull request in Spark
Spark-48185, but still getting this error!
Can someone please suggest a solution for the above issue!

Please follow the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78300174/1028537
In short you need to use the options found in Spark itself, which aren't well documented, to run on jdk17: JavaModuleOptions.
You can find this in the build files as well: pom.xml test args.
Spark connect features it too: spark-connect-scala-client:
-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions \
  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED \
  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED \
  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED \
  --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED \
  --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED \
  --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED \
  --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED \
  --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED \
  --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED \
  --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED \
  --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED \
  --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED \
  --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED \
  --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED \
  --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED \
  -Djdk.reflect.useDirectMethodHandle=false \
  -Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true


Thank you for the reply, Chris.  However, I was not able to resolve the above issue with the above options.  I have updated my post above with an excerpt from my pom.xml with the suggested options, I have also included them in maven plugin as well. But without any luck!

you should specify how you are actually running your application

It's a Java Spring boot application running on a local machine (spark.master=local[*]).

but how do you actually run it (not where it is running) - do you run from maven, build a jar, run via unit tests etc.  However you run it needs those parameters as well

Apologies for not being clear!  I am exploring a PoC and currently running directly from IntelliJ with maven (but not via unit tests).  The plan is to make a jar file and kick it off from a REST API controller.  The specific reason I am using Spark4.0-preview1 is to use it with Java 17 and Spring boot 3.2.X.

np, you should probably add those parameters to the intellij start vm jvm args section to get it running, it won't take that information from the pom.  Your jar file running will also require it

Adding the above as VM Options worked, Chris!  Thanks so much for the solution, appreciate all your help!
